# Java Date forcing BST "timezone"

Tags: java, date

In JAVA, how can I make sure that all dates are returned as GMT dates ?

For example, even if I try to force a DateFormat with GMT locale, it's applying some sort of logic that retrieves a BST date.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat dd = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    dd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Date parse = dd.parse("Out 29 23:00:00 GMT 2011");
    Date parse2 = dd.parse("Out 30 23:00:00 GMT 2011"); 
    System.out.println(parse); // Prints "Sun Oct 30 00:00:00 BST 2011"
    System.out.println(parse2); // Prints "Sun Oct 30 23:00:00 GMT 2011"
    System.out.println(Locale.getDefault()); // Prints "en_US"
    System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());  // Prints "Europe/London"
}
```

Where is the BST coming from ? Is it related to daylight saving times ? TimeZone class says otherwwise.

```
    System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT").inDaylightTime(parse)); // Prints "false"
    System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT").inDaylightTime(parse2)); // Prints "false"
```

The default system locale is en_US.

Edit: Based on Basil Bourque's response, I can get both prints to GMT dates, if I change the default time zone to GMT:

```
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Comment: The time zone applies to the `DateFormat`, not to the `Date`, which has no concept of time zone. You are passing the `Date` to `println`, which is not using anything having to do with your `DateFormat` to create its output.

Comment: @GriffeyDog that deserves to be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: For the record… Beware of calling [`TimeZone.setDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-). Good for a quick test. But risky in production as it immediately affects all current and future code running in all threads of all apps in that JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Mystery

Are you sure your comments on both `System.out.println` lines are correct? I expect output from both lines to have the same time zone, either `BST` or `GMT`.

If you are certain those are correct, please post a complete example of working code. Also document your default locale and time zone.

## Fully Working Example

Here is my version of your code transformed into a fully working example. I deduce from the `BST` and `out` that this is Portuguese Brazil locale.

```
java.util.Locale.setDefault( new Locale.Builder().setLanguage( "pt" ).setRegion( "BR" ).build() );  // **HACK* Think twice before ever setting the default of your JVM’s locale or time zone. Generally a bad idea.
java.text.DateFormat dd = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat( "MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" );
dd.setTimeZone( java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone( "GMT" ) );
Date parse = null;
Date parse2 = null;
try {
    parse = dd.parse( "Out 29 23:00:00 GMT 2011" );
    parse2 = dd.parse( "Out 30 23:00:00 GMT 2011" );
} catch ( ParseException ex ) {
    Logger.getLogger( JodaTimeWork.class.getName() ).log( Level.SEVERE , null , ex );
}
System.out.println( parse ); 
System.out.println( parse2 );
```

My output when running on a `US` locale and `America/Los_Angeles` time zone, thus the `PDT` time zone.

```
Sat Oct 29 16:00:00 PDT 2011
Sun Oct 30 16:00:00 PDT 2011
```

## No Time Zone On A `Date` Object

Be aware that a java.util.Date object has no time zone assigned†. Confusingly, the `toString` method implementation on that class applies the JVM’s current default time zone. So it *seems* like the Date object has a time zone, but it does not.

As the correct comment by [GriffeyDog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442451/griffeydog) said, the `DateFormat` object has a time zone but the Date object does not.

So I expect both of your `System.out.println` lines to emit text with the same time zone, as I said up top.

## Joda-Time | java.time

This confusing handling of time zones is one of many reasons to avoid java.util.Date/.Calendar & SimpleTextFormat. Those in the know use either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8. The java.time package was inspired by Joda-Time but is re-architected; each has its strengths and weaknesses.

### Example in Joda-Time

Here is an example in Joda-Time 2.7.

#### Time Zone on `DateTime`

A [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object in Joda-Time knows its own assigned time zone, unlike a java.util.Date object.

#### Incorrect Localization

Your input data’s use of an uppercase `O` for `Out` appears to be incorrect for Portuguese convention. My example corrects that to be lowercase. Joda-Time rejects the uppercase as invalid.

#### Code

```
String input1 = "out 29 23:00:00 GMT 2011";
String input2 = "out 30 23:00:00 GMT 2011";

Locale locale_pt_BR = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage( "pt" ).setRegion( "BR" ).build(); //
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT' yyyy" ).withLocale( locale_pt_BR ).withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );

DateTime dateTime1 = null;
DateTime dateTime2 = null;
DateTime dateTime1_Sao_Paulo = null;
DateTime dateTime2_Sao_Paulo = null;
try {
    dateTime1 = formatter.parseDateTime( input1 );
    dateTime2 = formatter.parseDateTime( input2 );
    // Adjust to "America/Sao_Paulo" time zone.
    DateTimeZone zone_Sao_Paulo = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Sao_Paulo" );
    dateTime1_Sao_Paulo = dateTime1.withZone( zone_Sao_Paulo );
    dateTime2_Sao_Paulo = dateTime2.withZone( zone_Sao_Paulo );
} catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
    // … Handle exception.
    System.out.println( "ERROR - Unexpected input for parsing into a date-time object." );
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "dateTime1 : " + dateTime1 );
System.out.println( "dateTime2 : " + dateTime2 );
System.out.println( "Adjusted to America/Sao_Paulo: " + dateTime1_Sao_Paulo + " & " + dateTime2_Sao_Paulo );
```

When run.

```
dateTime1 : 2011-10-29T23:00:00.000Z
dateTime2 : 2011-10-30T23:00:00.000Z
Adjusted to America/Sao_Paulo: 2011-10-29T21:00:00.000-02:00 & 2011-10-30T21:00:00.000-02:00
```

## ISO 8601

If you have any control or influence on the format of your input data, I strongly suggest changing to the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Example: `2015-02-15T19:39:11Z`.

## Time Zone

Avoid the 3 or 4 letter codes for time zones. They are neither standardized nor unique. `BST` for example can be:

- `British Summer Time` (outdated as of 1971 but still tops in Google hits)
- `Brazil Standard Time`
- `Bangladesh Standard Time`

Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Example: `America/Sao_Paulo`.

### 3-4 Letter Codes Refused By Joda-Time

Because of the frequent duplicate values, it is impossible to responsibly parse such values. So Joda-Time refuses to try.

Note in the example code above how I hard-coded the expected `GMT` value. See the single-quote marks (APOSTROPHE) around the "GMT" letters. That tells Joda-Time to expect and ignore that string while parsing.

This has a crucial consequence: With no identified time zone or offset-from-UTC, Joda-Time does not know how to interpret the date-time when parsing the string. We set the formatter to a time zone by which to interpret the string with no time zone or offset. If the string *did* have an offset, setting a time zone on the formatter has a different behavior: *after* parsing, the formatter adjusts the value to that time zone.

---

† Even more confusing, the java.util.Date actually *does* have a time zone, but buried deep within its implementation. That time zone is ignored for most practical purposes. So as shorthand, we say a j.u.Date has no time zone (effectively acts as if in UTC).